# Set cache-control in .user.ini

Tags: php, htaccess

I have a new AlmaLinux 9 installation with apache and php installed.  I am converting my .htaccess files to .user.ini   Although going well, I can't figure out the user.ini equivalent of the following:

```
# Cache all images and css for 7 days
<FilesMatch ".(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|css|js|ico)$">
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=604800, public"
</FilesMatch>
```

is it possible to set this in a .user.ini ?